# how to create asynk task so that i can with differnt parmeter

Tags: android

```
public class sendMesgTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        String msg = "";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                String result = sendMsg(params[0]);
                msg = getResult(result);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            if (msg.equals("1")) {

            }
        }

        public String sendMsg(String message) throws IOException, JSONException {

            try {

                String sendmsgurl = "http://api.lociiapp.com/api/message/sendmessage?member_id="
                        + 452
                        + "&to_id="
                        + 452
                        + "&message="
                        + message
                        + "&Notificationtype="
                        + "3"
                        + "&notificationId="
                        + (int) (Math.random() * 100000000)
                        + "&notify_status="
                        + "false";
                Log.e("Valueeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee", sendmsgurl);

                System.out.println("Valueeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee" + sendmsgurl);
                URL url = new URL(sendmsgurl);
                URLConnection urlcon = url.openConnection();
                jsonResp = convertToString(urlcon.getInputStream());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return jsonResp;
        }

        public String convertToString(InputStream is) {
            if (is != null) {
                Writer writer = new StringWriter();
                char[] buffer = new char[1024];
                try {
                    Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            is, "UTF-8"));
                    int n;
                    while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
                    }
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                } catch (IOException e) {

                } finally {
                    try {
                        is.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                    }
                }
                return writer.toString();
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        }

        private String getResult(String response) {

            String test = "";
            try {
                JSONObject json = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response)
                        .nextValue();
                test = json.getString("responseCode");
            } catch (JSONException e) {

            }
            return test;
        }
```

this is class asynk task  for sending message i am calling this asynk task like this   new sendMesgTask().execute("Rjected");

i want to call asynk task  like this way :

```
new sendMesgTask().execute(452,452,Rejected,3,(int) (Math.random() * 100000000),false);
```

please help me how to make class so that i can call like this way

Comment: use public class sendMesgTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> instead of public class sendMesgTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>

Comment: kindly edit in my code @Vera i am facing issue to initialize

Comment: Add Arguments to your constructor. `public sendMesgTask(String restUrl){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to use constructor approach like this

```
public class sendMesgTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {


int num1;
int num2;
String accept_reject;
int num3; 
int randum_number;
boolean bool;


public sendMesgTask(int num1, int num2, String accept_reject, int num3, int randum_number, boolean bool){

this.num1=num1;
this.num2= num2;
this.accept_reject = accept_reject;
this.num3 = num3;
this.randum_number=randum_number;
this.bool=bool;
}

.
.
//Your rest of code remains same
.
.
.



}
```

call like this

```
new sendMesgTask(452,452,Rejected,3,(int) (Math.random() * 100000000),false).execute();
```

EDIT:1

```
new sendMesgTask(452,452,"Rejected",3,(int) (Math.random() * 100000000),false).execute();
```

OK, Got your problem

now in your doInBackground method call like this

```
String result = sendMsg(sendeid,recciveid,msg,type,status);
```

instead of

```
String result = sendMsg(params[0]);
```

Comment: edid my code i am unable to call funcation like ur mention

Comment: how to call constructore

Comment: @Anil se my EDIT:1 call like that

Comment: edit in full code coz i am calling web service also please tell  http://pastie.org/9560818

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use constructor of asynctask for that like below:

```
public class sendMesgTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        String msg = "";
        int i;
        String j;

        public sendMesgTask(int i, String j){

            this.i = i;
            this.j = j;

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                String result = sendMsg(params[0]);
                msg = getResult(result);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
```

now, you can use both i and j variable in whole asynctask class.

and call like:

```
new sendMesgTask(5,"test").execute();
```

Comment: String result = sendMsg(params[0]); here we have to add  String result = sendMsg(params[0],params[1],....); like this na

Comment: String result = sendMsg(params[0]);
                msg = getResult(result);  here facing error

Comment: what i have to write in doinbackground

Comment: i have tried ur code still facing issue  here compilte error  String result = sendMsg(i, j); here also  this.sender=sender;

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class sendMesgTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String> {

    String msg = "";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Object... params) {
        try {
            String result = sendMsg(params[0]);
            msg = getResult(result);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (msg.equals("1")) {

        }
    }

    public String sendMsg(String message) throws IOException, JSONException {

        try {

            String sendmsgurl = "http://api.lociiapp.com/api/message/sendmessage?member_id="
                    + 452
                    + "&to_id="
                    + 452
                    + "&message="
                    + message
                    + "&Notificationtype="
                    + "3"
                    + "&notificationId="
                    + (int) (Math.random() * 100000000)
                    + "&notify_status="
                    + "false";
            Log.e("Valueeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee", sendmsgurl);

            System.out.println("Valueeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee" + sendmsgurl);
            URL url = new URL(sendmsgurl);
            URLConnection urlcon = url.openConnection();
            jsonResp = convertToString(urlcon.getInputStream());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonResp;
    }

    public String convertToString(InputStream is) {
        if (is != null) {
            Writer writer = new StringWriter();
            char[] buffer = new char[1024];
            try {
                Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        is, "UTF-8"));
                int n;
                while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            } catch (IOException e) {

            } finally {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
            }
            return writer.toString();
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    private String getResult(String response) {

        String test = "";
        try {
            JSONObject json = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response)
                    .nextValue();
            test = json.getString("responseCode");
        } catch (JSONException e) {

        }
        return test;
    }
```

Comment: The method sendMsg(String) in the type Notifcationadapter is not applicable for the arguments (Object) error is coming

Comment: So go with String and break it up.